# スタティックNAT(静的NAT)の設定について

Tags: network

会社で固定のグローバルIPアドレスの回線を契約した上で、スタティックNATの設定をしてTV会議を導入しようとしています。
スタティックNATの設定は市販のルーターを購入すれば簡単にGUIベースで設定できるものでしょうか？
あるいは設定自体はコマンドを打たないといけないものでしょうか？

わかる範囲でご教示いただければ幸甚です。

Answer (score 2):

はい、市販の「家庭用ルーター」で可能です。家庭用ルータの場合コマンドラインで設定する手段が提供されていなくて GUI でしか設定できないものがほとんどです。逆に言うと、設定内容をテキストに保存しておいて新しいマシンが１台追加されたらその設定ファイルに１台追加してルータに食わせるみたいなことができません。いちいち必ず GUI 経由で設定しなければならないので、テキスト形式でエビちゃんが残せないようなものばかりです。
 # GUI が簡単と思っているなら大間違い。

業務用ルータは高性能でイイんですけど、扱う側にそれなりの技量が必要。

ちなみに {狭い意味での} NAT でなくって NAPT ですよね。その辺は誤解なきよう。

---

まあテレビ会議だけしたいのであれば UPnP できればよいのであって、会議ソフトのほうに UPnP 機能があれば「一切何の設定もしなくて」できるので (リモートアシスタントなんかまさにそれ) 案件次第。

マルチポストはあまり好まれないと思います。
https://teratail.com/questions/173831

Comment: 何を指しているのか分からなかったのですが、「エビちゃん」は広く使われている用語でしょうか？ / 家庭用ルーターでもGUI(web画面)から設定をバックアップ・インポートできるものはいくつか使った覚えがあります。

Comment: エビデンス（証拠）のことです。ウチの家庭用ルータは設定内容を保存・復帰できましたけど、バイナリ形式でした。「ちゃんと設定した」という証拠にするにはちょっと薄弱っすね。

Comment: 自分のところでもエビって略すので結構広域で使われているかと。